# Javascript function - parameter length

Tags: javascript

I am calling a javascript function from hyperlink as shown below.

```
<a href="javascript:redirect('param1','param2','http://google.com');">Do this</a>
```

In this case the redirect() function gets called as expected and redirected to the url in third parameter. But if the url parameter is a big one (lets say >200 characters), javascript function never gets called. Is there any limit on the parameter length? I do need the URL to be that big because I am passing few encrypted parameters and they are huge......

---------edit----------

here is one example of lengthy URL parameter

```
<a href="javascript:redirect('A-0', '07', 'http://localhost:9083/xxxxx/aaa/bbbb/ccccc/redirectApply.do?token=9BsPtrGQPEYWv6dvbP9hsX9skeghTHnonkKZtsqrkZXSf7gKqKRYdo2i6CpcLOWxroqrWEDhyosk%0D%0A1aD1tQ0OBHHfsVjPKb%2B1kSFzjCg8lKyoGropGWc%2Bc7oCT8%2BYItwX');">
```

Comment: maybe not the amount of characters, but specific characters break your function? Provide URL and the implementation of the function. And by the way, better bind click handler

Comment: @Darhazer.. thanks for your comment.. here is one of those URLs.. 'http://localhost:9083/xxx/xxxx/xxx/Xxxx/redirectApply.do?token=9BsPtrGQPEYWv6dvbP9hsX9skeghTHnonkKZtsqrkZXSf7gKqKRYdo2i6CpcLOWxroqrWEDhyosk%0D%0A1aD1tQ0OBHHfsVjPKb%2B1kSFzjCg8lKyoGropGWc%2Bc7oCT8%2BYItwX'

Comment: I remember that I saw a similar problem and removing all spaces (after commas in your case) from javascript attribute helped (as browsers sometimes decide that it is probably not all an attribute if it is so long and corrupts javascript). There is no limit this low in javascript itself

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding the javascript right in the href attribute, you could attach it dynamically.

Ex:

```
<a id="example_link">Do this</a>
```

Then:

```
document.getElementById('example_link').onclick = function(){
    redirect('param1','param2','http://google.com');
    return false;
};
```

If you're using a JavaScript library like jQuery, or if you have a better way of identifying the anchors than by ID, there are better solutions.

Comment: that URL is dynamically generated.. how would I pass it to the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript:redirect, I would dynamically change the href of the a tag. This allows browser to use the "Open Link in new tab", Ctrl-click or similar functionality and probably wouldn't have the problem you are mentioning. This also lets the user see where they are going when they hover over the link.

Comment: I have some logic in javascript function that decides whether user should be redirected or not..