# Unterminated String literal - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a parameter to Javascript function and that parameter may contain special characters like %. How do I escape these characters so that they are properly passed to JS? These parameters are generated dynamically so I cannot identify each and every single character and put an escape character there.

This is the JSP part...

```
<a href="javascript:redirect('<bean:write property="appId" name="appl"/>','<bean:write property="propId" name="appl"/>','<bean:write property="url" name="appl"/>');">
                                click this
                            </a>
```

this is the generated part...

```
<a href="javascript:redirect('A-0', '07', 'http://localhost:9083/xxxxx/aaa/bbbb/ccccc/redirectApply.do?token=9BsPtrGQPEYWv6dvbP9hsX9skeghTHnonkKZtsqrkZXSf7gKqKRYdo2i6CpcLOWxroqrWEDhyosk%0D%0A1aD1tQ0OBHHfsVjPKb%2B1kSFzjCg8lKyoGropGWc%2Bc7oCT8%2BYItwX');">
```

It looks like the character '%' is causing the issue. I looked at error console in Firefox and it shows the string upto ****WEDhyosk and says string is not terminated........

This question is related to an earlier [question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745018/javscript-function-parameter-length), but since I didn't have a clear understanding of the issue back then, I am reposting,

Comment: %0D is the equivalent of a carriage return. It seems this is being misinterpreted as an end-of-line character.

Comment: You should rather updates your previous question with the new information and maybe notify the answerers as well.

Comment: thats bad... that part of the string is an encrypted param coming from a third party service.. :(

Comment: Carriage return would terminate the string though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode("www.google.com","UTF-8");
```

The browser should then automatically decode the string when the link is clicked.